# JMETER Record a scenario that contains calls using microsoft remote desktop protocol

Tags: jmeter

One of the steps of my scenario opens a Remote Desktop Connection (RDC - Microsoft) and do some actions (HTTP/HTTPS) on the remote server and close it, and continue on the local Computer (HTTP/HTTPS).

And we should absolutly study the performance impact of the RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) calls by several clients.

We use and will use JMETER for all of our projects. (if possible)

I know that jmeter does not support RDP protocol.

But my question is : Is there any solution to capture RDP calls by JMeter for example a plugin that could answer to this kind of challenge.

Thank You.

My best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to record Remote Desktop traffic as it doesn't look like something you want to replay with increased amount of threads.

1. The easiest way is configure browser on 2nd machine to use 1st machine as a proxy server.
2. If for some reason point 1 is not achievable (DMZ, firewall, etc.) you can work it around using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) on the 2nd machine just the same way as you do it on local. Once you finished recording - you can just copy and paste relevant requests to the 1st machine - it is possible to use clipboard over RDP.
3. If point 2 cannot be implemented - you can use an external proxy, i.e. offered by [Mobile Recorder](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder) service

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I may not have been enough clear in my message .

It’s exactly what we must measure , RDP calls in // by several threads (simulated by jmeter) so these calls should be replayed.

This is a part of our performance test objectives.

Regards

Comment: JMeter doesn't have support of RDP protocol. As far as I know [LoadRunner does](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/4-Tips-for-Replaying-Remote-Desktop-Protocol-RDP-scripts-in/ba-p/6063293#.VikMhWScHPA). If you have to do it via JMeter you'll have to consider some Java library which provides Remote Desktop Connectivity like [properJavaRDP](http://properjavardp.sourceforge.net/) from [JSR223 Sampler](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) but you'll have to write some groovy/java code.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks,

Is it possible to record the scenario with "selenium / webdriver" and integrate it into JMeter ? So to use the Multi-threading benefits of jmeter to simulate virtual users ?

Answer (score 0):

I may not have been enough clear in my message .

It’s exactly what we must measure , RDP calls in // by several threads (simulated by jmeter) so these calls should be replayed.

This is a part of our performance test objectives.

Regards